# Estimate proportion of polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I need:

> - Estimate the proportion of polynomial of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{F}_q[x]$, with a large $q$ that are irreducible
> - Estimate the proportion of polynomial of degree $n$ that descompose totally over $\mathbb{F}_q$.

So, my first problem is what you refer by "proportion", I though write the expression of the form, for instance, $q^n+\mathcal{O}(q^{n/2})$.

On the other hand, I know that the number $N_{q}(n)$ of monic irreducible polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_{q}[x]$ of degree $n$ is given by $$N_q(n)=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{d\mid n}{\mu(d)q^{\frac{n}{d}}}$$ But anyway, I don't know how estimate a proportion of this polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_{q}[x]$. Can help me pls! Thanks!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848146/number-of-monic-irreducible-polynomials-over-a-finite-field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first, there are $q^{n+1}$ polynomials of degree $n$ because each coefficient has $q$ choices.  You are supposed to estimate the number of these that are reducible, then divide by $q^{n+1}$ to get the proportion.  The degree of one factor has to be less than or equal to $n/2\ \ldots$

For the second, you need to estimate the number of products of first degree polynomials.  You need to think about rearrangements of factors producing the same ultimate polynomial.