# Number of irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I'm a little bit confused that the number of irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$.

In Dummit & Foote's textbook(Abstract algebra, 3rd), the number of $\textbf{irreducible}$ polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ is given by the following equation:$$\frac{1}{n}\cdot\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\cdot p^{\tfrac{n}{d}}.$$

Is this only counting the number of $\textbf{monic irreducible}$ polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$?

There is no constraint about $\textbf{monic}$ in the textbook. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, "monic" , see the other posts about this topic, e.g., [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848146/number-of-monic-irreducible-polynomials-over-a-finite-field), and in particualr [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152880/how-many-irreducible-polynomials-of-degree-n-exist-over-mathbbf-p).

Comment: **Theorem:** Let $\mu(n)$ denote the Möbius function. The number of **monic** irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ is the [Necklace Polynomial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_polynomial") 
$$M_n(q) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{d | n} \mu(d) q^{n/d}.$$

**To get the number of irreducible polynomials just multiply by $q - 1$**

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you. In Dummit & Foote's textbook, this theorem that 'the polynomial $x^{p^{n}}-x\in\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$ is precisely the product of all the distinct $\textbf{irreducible}$ polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_{p}[x]$ of degree $d$ runs through all divisors of $n$' was used to derive that formula. So, I was confused for the monic condition. I think it needs to be fixed, isn't it?